# Is there a psychological explanation for the age of 18 being important in many societies?

Tags: developmental-psychology

The **age of eighteen** is an age that in many societies gives rise to various additional rights and responsibilities.

- Is there a scientific reason for assigning such right and responsibilities at the age of 18?
- What are some of reasons and history for this convention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [cursory search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_majority) strongly suggests that the distinction is arbitrary and practical, with little link to developmental science.

I can find no evidence for any particularly compelling biological change centered around the age of 18.  That, along with the fact that the age of eighteen is *not* a universal age-of-majority, makes me say that there is no scientific basis for the choice.